# Is there a way to hide extension contexts in the chrome devtools context dropdown

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I work on a project integrated into another website through an iframe. This website has several other iframes.

When I want to directly execute code on the console I have to select my project's iframe but has i have many extensions on chrome the dropdow to select the right context is filled with all my extensions for each iframe (cf screenshot).

[image]

Is there a way to hide the extentions iframes from this list ?

Comment: There's no way other than editing the source code of devtools (which you can do temporarily via [devtools-on-devtools](/q/12291138)). You can suggest this feature in https://crbug.com.